# AI: Cutting out a tshirt from a picture

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, watson

I have basic theory of AI and deep learning techniques. However, most examples of things like Neural Nets are *understanding* and classifying images.

What I need is to be able to say *"this is a photo containing a tshirt (on a person or just lying down), give me the cutout (alpha mask etc.) of the tshirt without anything else in the background*.

What AI techniques would you suggest? I am open to either building the AI or using services. I have tried the Watson API visual recognition service, but again it seems to be for a different (classification) problems.

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a problem of *image-segmentation*.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is object **detection** not object recognition. Object Detection is the task of 'cropping' down a certain area of an image and classifying it.

There are a few services out there, try [Google Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/).

Comment: As far as I can see the Google Vision API does very similar things to the IBM Watson - image recognition and labelling, but not actually isolating the objects from the other objects

Comment: "Label Detection
Detect broad sets of categories within an image, ranging from modes of transportation to animals."; "Logo Detection
Detect popular product logos within an image."; "Landmark Detection
Detect popular natural and man-made structures within an image."

Comment: Yes and you can specify custom classifiers, but the API does not return pixel data for a mask that would cut out the detected objects

Comment: If that's what you need, then you need to implement a full model.
State of the art involves convolutional networks but there are also other traditional methods like Haar Cascade. Take a look here: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/06/20/detecting-cats-in-images-with-opencv/